# Existence of odd mod $p$ Galois representations whose image is $p'$-group

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $K$ be a number field and let $G_K$ be the absolute Galois group of $K$. Let $p$ be an odd prime and $\mathbb{F}_p$ be a finite field of order $p$. Can we always find a continuous representation $\overline{\rho}:G_{K}\to \rm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$ such that

1. $\overline{\rho}$ is unramified at any place of $K$ above $p$.
2. The order of the image $\text{Im}(\overline{\rho})$ of $\overline{\rho}$ is prime to $p$.
3. $\overline{\rho}$ is totally odd, i.e. $\det(\overline{\rho}(c))=-1$ for all complex conjugations $c$.
4. The restriction $\overline{\rho}|G_{K(\zeta_{p})}$ of $\overline{\rho}$ on the open subgroup $ G_{K(\zeta_{p})}$ of $G_K$ is absolutely irreducible where $K(\zeta_{p})$ is the $p$-th cyclotomic field field of $K$？

Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: By 2, the image lies in a maximal subgroup other than the Borels. Unless you are in the exceptional cases, which cannot occur for all $p$, the image is in the normaliser of a split or a non-split Cartan group. Therefore you are looking for a quadratic extension of $K$ and an abelian extension above it such that the other conditions are verified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take an $S_3$-extension $L/K$ in which all primes above $p$ split and which is odd at all real places of $K$.  (These are easy to construct, take the Galois closure of $x^3 - a x - b$ where $a$ and $b$ in $K$ are chosen to have the right local properties at $p$ and $\infty$ by weak approximation, and if $K$ is totally imaginary choose another local condition to avoid the $A_3$ case). Then

$$G_K \rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(L/K) \simeq  S_3 \hookrightarrow \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_p)$$

has all the required properties when $p > 3$.  If $p=2$ it is not possible because $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_2) \simeq S_3$ has no subgroups of odd order which act absolutely ireducible. If $p=3$, replace $S_3$ by the dihedral group $D_8$ of order $8$. (This is not as elementary as the $S_3$ case but is still easy.)

Comment: thanks for your nice answer. Do you have any reference about "by weak approximation" or more details about it?

Comment: Weak approximation (in this setting) is just the Chinese Remainder Theorem plus epsilon. That is you can find $a$ and $b$ satisfying congruences modulo some power of a prime $p$ but also lying inside some ball at the infinite places. For $\mathbf{Q}$ it's like saying you can solve the congruence $r \equiv 2 \mod 7$ with a rational number $r \in \mathbf{Q}$ that is between $4$ and $5$. If you understand this example you understand the general case. (If you look at weak approximation on wikipedia this is just the case of the additive group which is much easier.)